# Getting error that I can't understand

Tags: java, primitive-types

The below code is giving me a "Cannot invoke nextDouble() on the primitive type double" error. I'm fairly new to Java, can anyone provide some guidance on what's causing it?

```
public static double[][] getArray(int row,int column){

    double [][] a = new double[row][column];
    double input;

    for (int x=0; x<a.length; x++){
        for (int y=0; y<a[x].length; y++){
            a[x][y] = input.nextDouble();
        }
    }

    return a;
}
```

Comment: Look at how you have declared `input`!

Comment: `input` is a double. There is no method `nextDouble()` in `double`. In fact there's no methods whatsoever, since it's a primitive. Time to hit the tutorials: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: what you want is Random input = new Random();

Comment: Scanner class has `nextDouble()`

Comment: What you want to do here...?

Comment: Note that your `input` is not initialised. further, double does not have any methods as `nextDouble()`. If you want to generate random double values, you may use `Random` class. If you want to accept the values from user, use Scanner class.

Answer (score 3):

You have used the type `double` for the variable `input`, and anyways you can't invoke a method on a primitive type.
If you want to scan a double from the console, use the type `Scanner` like this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

So, your method should like this:

```
public static double[][] getArray(int row,int column){

    double [][] a = new double[row][column];
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int x=0; x<a.length; x++){
        for (int y=0; y<a[x].length; y++){
            a[x][y] = input.nextDouble();
        }
    }

    return a;
}
```